# How to boot an NTFS Partition in Archlinux

Tags: linux, windows, archlinux, ntfs

I just did a dual boot Win10/arch, i'm currently meeting an issue where I successfully auto-mount a NTFS partition but only on Read-Only and I need to "write" permission on it, I followed this method in order to boot at the start.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hrm51ufjJc

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on http://unix.stackexchange.com  OR http://superuser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you disable fast boot in Windows?
If you didn't, don't worry. I made this script. If fast boot isn't disabled, it will delete a file used to make windows boot faster. For some reason you must run first ntfsfix before being able to mount your partition.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo ls >/dev/null
if sudo -n true 2>/dev/null; then 
    echo -e "\033[0;36mGot temporary sudo session. This script won't work if the volume is already mounted.\n \033[0m" 
    fdisk -l | grep -C0 'basic data'
    echo -e "\n"
echo -e -n "Enter windows partition identifier (format: \033[0;36msdX#\033[0m): "
read disk
sudo ntfsfix /dev/$disk >/dev/null
sudo mkdir /kek
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/$disk /kek
sudo umount /kek
sudo rmdir /kek
sudo -k
echo "Temporary sudo session killed."
else
    echo "Pls try again"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Type `lsblk` in the terminal to search for the windows partition.
Must be something like sda1 or sda2.

Copy paste this in the terminal `sudo ntfsfix /dev/{windows partitions}`.

Example:

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1`.

Hope this helps.